# nginx routing POST requests to another script via fastcgi

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

Given an nginx+php-fpm setup like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

which works just fine, if i change the fastcgi_param to the following:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/route.php?r=$request_uri;
```

Are POST parameters together with cookies and everything else also passed to route.php transparently?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois i'm currently afs (away from server) and can't test till monday, but i usually keep at least the sources with me.

Comment: You should not have `?r=$request_uri` in the `SCRIPT_FILENAME`. That parameter needs to be the filename of the script.

Comment: @RichardSmith so, uhm, should i mess with `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING` instead?